# Is there a way to run Plato on coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, plato

I've written all my server side code and Coffeescript and I'm wondering if there is a way to run [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) on it?

Comment: compiling your coffee code and run plato on that is no option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plans to add coffeescript support but it doesn't currently support it: [via this thread](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato/issues/24)